# Handling text input events in React/React-Native in a cross-platform manner? (e.target.value vs e.nativeTarget.text)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, events

I'm trying to re-use as much code as possible across platforms. I've got some `input` elements I render which are rendered by the same container element.

**In React I handle it like this:**

```js
  handleFieldChange(fieldName, evt) {
    const { formValues } = this.state;
    formValues[fieldName] = evt.target.value;  // This line differs
    this.setState({ formValues });
  }
```

**But in React Native:**
`evt.target` is a number and it seems the only way is to do:

```js
  handleFieldChange(fieldName, evt) {
    const { formValues } = this.state;
    formValues[fieldName] = evt.nativeTarget.text; // This line differs
    this.setState({ formValues });
  }
```

Is there any code I can use across platforms?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a universal InputField component that checks which platform you are using and render the corresponding component and in this component you should handle the events depending on the platform. Other components which will use this new component should not care about the platform at all.